# Proper name for a "polytope" when defined by linear functionals

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, functional-inequalities

Is there a name for the set of functions $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ which satisfy a finite set of equations $\int_0^1 f(x)w_i(x)dx\geq c_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$? If $f$ had a discrete domain and the integral was replaced with summation, the feasible set could have been called a *polytope*..

Comment: You might find [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/156879/34894) to be helpful. I would guess that the best name for these would be "infinite-dimensional polytopes"

Comment: Thanks a lot, @BenGrossmann. I thought about using Infinite dimensional polytope, but that might also refer to a polytope in $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$, so it might be a bit ambiguous here..